# How to initiate creation of a Facebook page for an Open Graph object?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I noticed that simply invoking the Facebook Linter on my object doesn't work, but as soon as I click the Facebook Like on the page, a Facebook page gets created.

Before "liking", hitting http://graph.facebook.com/?ids={MY_OBJ_URL} returns:

```
{
   "{MY_OBJ_URL}": {
      "id": "{MY_OBJ_URL}"
   }
}
```

after "liking", it returns a valid id

```
{
   "{MY_OBJ_URL}": {
      "id": "{id}"
   }
}
```

so that going to http://www.facebook.com/{id} takes me to the Facebook page counterpart of my Open Graph Object.

The question is, is earning a first "like" a requirement for a page to be created on Facebook? Or is there another way to ensure the page gets created?